# Strange Java memory issue

Tags: java, memory, memory-management

This is a follow-up to this thread: [Java Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23943122/1839951). I got some useful advice in that thread, and now have more clarity on the main issue. In that thread they suggested they main problem was the declaration of a large two-dimensional array that required a huge chunk of contiguous memory; but I am seeing a similar problem even after addressing that issue by declaring each row of the array separately.

I am trying to declare a large two-dimensional array, and my program has been crashing and running out of memory sometime during the declaration, despite apparently having more than enough free space for it. Instead of declaring it with

```
float[][] A = new float[NUM_SEQ_TOTAL_P1][NUM_SEQ_TOTAL_P2];
```

I am declaring it the following way, to decrease the necessary amount of contiguous memory. I am also printing the amount of free memory after each row is initialized in order to try to pinpoint the problem.

```
float[][] A = new float[NUM_SEQ_TOTAL_P1][];

        if (VERBOSE) {
            System.out.println("After initial array allocation");
            maxMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();  
            allocatedMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();  
            freeMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();  
            totalFreeMemory = freeMemory + (maxMemory - allocatedMemory);
            System.out.println("free memory: " + freeMemory);  
            System.out.println("allocated memory: " + allocatedMemory);  
            System.out.println("max memory: " + maxMemory);  
            System.out.println("total free memory: " + totalFreeMemory);   
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SEQ_TOTAL_P1; ++i) {
            A[i] = new float[NUM_SEQ_TOTAL_P2];
            if (VERBOSE) {
                System.out.println("After allocation for row " + i);
                maxMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();  
                allocatedMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();  
                freeMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();  
                totalFreeMemory = freeMemory + (maxMemory - allocatedMemory);
                System.out.println("free memory: " + freeMemory);  
                System.out.println("allocated memory: " + allocatedMemory);  
                System.out.println("max memory: " + maxMemory);  
                System.out.println("total free memory: " + totalFreeMemory);   
            }
        }
```

When running this on an example instance with NUM_SEQ_TOTAL_P1 = 13001, NUM_SEQ_TOTAL_P2 = 12501, the program crashed when trying to initialize row 12009, despite seeming to have around 1.4G of memory available.

Here is the output right before the crash:

```
After allocation for row 12007
free memory: 1206742048
allocated memory: 6688342016
max memory: 6990856192
total free memory: 1509256224
After allocation for row 12008
free memory: 1206742048
allocated memory: 6688342016
max memory: 6990856192
total free memory: 1509256224
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x0000000755600000, 203948032, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 203948032 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/ubuntu/submission_2pn/ACPC2014_Agent/hs_err_pid22209.log
```

And here are the contents of the error file hs_err_pid22209.log (with the "dynamic libraries" section omitted for brevity).

```
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 203948032 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2769), pid=22209, tid=140261598435072
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_55-b14) (build 1.7.0_55-b14)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f913c071000):  VMThread [stack: 0x00007f9132b01000,0x00007f9132c02000] [id=22213]

Stack: [0x00007f9132b01000,0x00007f9132c02000],  sp=0x00007f9132c00470,  free space=1021k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x917b35]  VMError::report_and_die()+0x175
V  [libjvm.so+0x468144]  report_vm_out_of_memory(char const*, int, unsigned long, char const*)+0x74
V  [libjvm.so+0x79a81b]  os::pd_commit_memory(char*, unsigned long, unsigned long, bool)+0x20b
V  [libjvm.so+0x7950df]  os::commit_memory(char*, unsigned long, unsigned long, bool)+0x1f
V  [libjvm.so+0x8053cb]  PSVirtualSpace::expand_by(unsigned long)+0x5b
V  [libjvm.so+0x7f519b]  PSOldGen::expand_by(unsigned long) [clone .part.80]+0x1b
V  [libjvm.so+0x7f535b]  PSOldGen::expand(unsigned long) [clone .part.81]+0xdb
V  [libjvm.so+0x7f6288]  PSOldGen::resize(unsigned long)+0x188
V  [libjvm.so+0x7fd2e3]  PSParallelCompact::invoke_no_policy(bool)+0x9c3
V  [libjvm.so+0x80350d]  PSScavenge::invoke()+0x17d
V  [libjvm.so+0x7b9b33]  ParallelScavengeHeap::failed_mem_allocate(unsigned long)+0x63
V  [libjvm.so+0x919544]  VM_ParallelGCFailedAllocation::doit()+0x84
V  [libjvm.so+0x91d9e7]  VM_Operation::evaluate()+0x47
V  [libjvm.so+0x91c3b8]  VMThread::evaluate_operation(VM_Operation*)+0x318
V  [libjvm.so+0x91c819]  VMThread::loop()+0x219
V  [libjvm.so+0x91cc62]  VMThread::run()+0x72
V  [libjvm.so+0x7974e2]  java_start(Thread*)+0xf2

VM_Operation (0x00007f91448863a0): ParallelGCFailedAllocation, mode: safepoint, requested by thread 0x00007f913c00a000


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00007f913c0a1800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=22219, stack(0x00007f9132372000,0x00007f9132473000)]
  0x00007f913c09f000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=22218, stack(0x00007f9132473000,0x00007f9132574000)]
  0x00007f913c09c000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=22217, stack(0x00007f9132574000,0x00007f9132675000)]
  0x00007f913c09a000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=22216, stack(0x00007f9132675000,0x00007f9132776000)]
  0x00007f913c077800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=22215, stack(0x00007f91328ff000,0x00007f9132a00000)]
  0x00007f913c075800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=22214, stack(0x00007f9132a00000,0x00007f9132b01000)]
  0x00007f913c00a000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_blocked, id=22210, stack(0x00007f9144787000,0x00007f9144888000)]

Other Threads:
=>0x00007f913c071000 VMThread [stack: 0x00007f9132b01000,0x00007f9132c02000] [id=22213]
  0x00007f913c0ac000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x00007f9132271000,0x00007f9132372000] [id=22220]

VM state:at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x00007f913c005ea0] ExpandHeap_lock - owner thread: 0x00007f913c071000
[0x00007f913c006520] Threads_lock - owner thread: 0x00007f913c071000
[0x00007f913c006a20] Heap_lock - owner thread: 0x00007f913c00a000

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 1707008K, used 0K [0x0000000763c00000, 0x0000000800000000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 854016K, 0% used [0x0000000763c00000,0x0000000763c00000,0x0000000797e00000)
  from space 852992K, 0% used [0x00000007cbf00000,0x00000007cbf00000,0x0000000800000000)
  to   space 852992K, 0% used [0x0000000797e00000,0x0000000797e00000,0x00000007cbf00000)
 ParOldGen       total 4884480K, used 3291458K [0x000000062b400000, 0x0000000755600000, 0x0000000763c00000)
  object space 4884480K, 67% used [0x000000062b400000,0x00000006f4250948,0x0000000755600000)
 PSPermGen       total 21504K, used 5552K [0x0000000620e00000, 0x0000000622300000, 0x000000062b400000)
  object space 21504K, 25% used [0x0000000620e00000,0x000000062136c2a8,0x0000000622300000)

Card table byte_map: [0x00007f9140502000,0x00007f91413fc000] byte_map_base: 0x00007f913d3fb000

Polling page: 0x00007f9144898000

Code Cache  [0x00007f9139000000, 0x00007f9139280000, 0x00007f913c000000)
 total_blobs=673 nmethods=393 adapters=234 free_code_cache=46719Kb largest_free_block=47718656

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 822.060 Thread 0x00007f913c09c000  414             playingAgent.tartanian7.PlayerAction::access$0 (5 bytes)
Event: 822.061 Thread 0x00007f913c09c000 nmethod 414 0x00007f913909a490 code [0x00007f913909a5c0, 0x00007f913909a618]
Event: 825.774 Thread 0x00007f913c09f000  415             playingAgent.tartanian7.PokerUtils::countRoundDelimiters (42 bytes)
Event: 825.777 Thread 0x00007f913c09f000 nmethod 415 0x00007f913910cb10 code [0x00007f913910cc60, 0x00007f913910ce78]
Event: 833.158 Thread 0x00007f913c09c000  416             sun.misc.FloatingDecimal::<init> (205 bytes)
Event: 833.160 Thread 0x00007f913c09c000 nmethod 416 0x00007f9139252e50 code [0x00007f9139252fa0, 0x00007f9139253148]
Event: 868.741 Thread 0x00007f913c09f000  417             playingAgent.riverSolver.DoylesGameRiver2::getRiverStrategy (451 bytes)
Event: 869.143 Thread 0x00007f913c09f000 nmethod 417 0x00007f913926b790 code [0x00007f913926c300, 0x00007f9139276030]
Event: 873.572 Thread 0x00007f913c09c000  418             java.lang.String::toString (2 bytes)
Event: 873.573 Thread 0x00007f913c09c000 nmethod 418 0x00007f9139204350 code [0x00007f9139204480, 0x00007f91392044d8]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 870.681 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=296 (full 26):
 PSYoungGen      total 1589760K, used 155692K [0x0000000763c00000, 0x00000007f9700000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 746496K, 0% used [0x0000000763c00000,0x0000000763c00000,0x0000000791500000)
  from space 843264K, 18% used [0x00000007c5f80000,0x00000007cf78b148,0x00000007f9700000)
  to   space 852992K, 0% used [0x0000000791500000,0x0000000791500000,0x00000007c5600000)
 ParOldGen       total 4884480K, used 4320346K [0x000000062b400000, 0x0000000755600000, 0x0000000763c00000)
  object space 4884480K, 88% used [0x000000062b400000,0x0000000732f16a70,0x0000000755600000)
 PSPermGen       total 21504K, used 5550K [0x0000000620e00000, 0x0000000622300000, 0x000000062b400000)
  object space 21504K, 25% used [0x0000000620e00000,0x000000062136baa8,0x0000000622300000)
}
Event: 887.064 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=297 (full 26):
 PSYoungGen      total 1589760K, used 902188K [0x0000000763c00000, 0x00000007f9700000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 746496K, 100% used [0x0000000763c00000,0x0000000791500000,0x0000000791500000)
  from space 843264K, 18% used [0x00000007c5f80000,0x00000007cf78b148,0x00000007f9700000)
  to   space 852992K, 0% used [0x0000000791500000,0x0000000791500000,0x00000007c5600000)
 ParOldGen       total 4884480K, used 4320346K [0x000000062b400000, 0x0000000755600000, 0x0000000763c00000)
  object space 4884480K, 88% used [0x000000062b400000,0x0000000732f16a70,0x0000000755600000)
 PSPermGen       total 21504K, used 5552K [0x0000000620e00000, 0x0000000622300000, 0x000000062b400000)
  object space 21504K, 25% used [0x0000000620e00000,0x000000062136c000,0x0000000622300000)
Event: 887.089 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=297 (full 26):
 PSYoungGen      total 1599488K, used 19832K [0x0000000763c00000, 0x00000007fc580000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 746496K, 0% used [0x0000000763c00000,0x0000000763c00000,0x0000000791500000)
  from space 852992K, 2% used [0x0000000791500000,0x000000079285e170,0x00000007c5600000)
  to   space 852992K, 0% used [0x00000007c8480000,0x00000007c8480000,0x00000007fc580000)
 ParOldGen       total 4884480K, used 4320346K [0x000000062b400000, 0x0000000755600000, 0x0000000763c00000)
  object space 4884480K, 88% used [0x000000062b400000,0x0000000732f16a70,0x0000000755600000)
 PSPermGen       total 21504K, used 5552K [0x0000000620e00000, 0x0000000622300000, 0x000000062b400000)
  object space 21504K, 25% used [0x0000000620e00000,0x000000062136c000,0x0000000622300000)
}
Event: 887.429 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=298 (full 26):
 PSYoungGen      total 1599488K, used 766328K [0x0000000763c00000, 0x00000007fc580000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 746496K, 100% used [0x0000000763c00000,0x0000000791500000,0x0000000791500000)
  from space 852992K, 2% used [0x0000000791500000,0x000000079285e170,0x00000007c5600000)
  to   space 852992K, 0% used [0x00000007c8480000,0x00000007c8480000,0x00000007fc580000)
 ParOldGen       total 4884480K, used 4320346K [0x000000062b400000, 0x0000000755600000, 0x0000000763c00000)
  object space 4884480K, 88% used [0x000000062b400000,0x0000000732f16a70,0x0000000755600000)
 PSPermGen       total 21504K, used 5552K [0x0000000620e00000, 0x0000000622300000, 0x000000062b400000)
  object space 21504K, 25% used [0x0000000620e00000,0x000000062136c000,0x0000000622300000)
Event: 887.799 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=298 (full 26):
 PSYoungGen      total 1647104K, used 757446K [0x0000000763c00000, 0x00000007fe780000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 794112K, 0% used [0x0000000763c00000,0x0000000763c00000,0x0000000794380000)
  from space 852992K, 88% used [0x00000007c8480000,0x00000007f6831848,0x00000007fc580000)
  to   space 852992K, 0% used [0x0000000794380000,0x0000000794380000,0x00000007c8480000)
 ParOldGen       total 4884480K, used 4320346K [0x000000062b400000, 0x0000000755600000, 0x0000000763c00000)
  object space 4884480K, 88% used [0x000000062b400000,0x0000000732f16a70,0x0000000755600000)
 PSPermGen       total 21504K, used 5552K [0x0000000620e00000, 0x0000000622300000, 0x000000062b400000)
  object space 21504K, 25% used [0x0000000620e00000,0x000000062136c000,0x0000000622300000)
}
Event: 921.229 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=299 (full 26):
 PSYoungGen      total 1647104K, used 1551558K [0x0000000763c00000, 0x00000007fe780000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 794112K, 100% used [0x0000000763c00000,0x0000000794380000,0x0000000794380000)
  from space 852992K, 88% used [0x00000007c8480000,0x00000007f6831848,0x00000007fc580000)
  to   space 852992K, 0% used [0x0000000794380000,0x0000000794380000,0x00000007c8480000)
 ParOldGen       total 4884480K, used 4320346K [0x000000062b400000, 0x0000000755600000, 0x0000000763c00000)
  object space 4884480K, 88% used [0x000000062b400000,0x0000000732f16a70,0x0000000755600000)
 PSPermGen       total 21504K, used 5552K [0x0000000620e00000, 0x0000000622300000, 0x000000062b400000)
  object space 21504K, 25% used [0x0000000620e00000,0x000000062136c2a8,0x0000000622300000)
Event: 921.312 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=299 (full 26):
 PSYoungGen      total 1647104K, used 238543K [0x0000000763c00000, 0x0000000800000000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 794112K, 0% used [0x0000000763c00000,0x0000000763c00000,0x0000000794380000)
  from space 852992K, 27% used [0x0000000794380000,0x00000007a2c73d88,0x00000007c8480000)
  to   space 852992K, 0% used [0x00000007cbf00000,0x00000007cbf00000,0x0000000800000000)
 ParOldGen       total 4884480K, used 4320469K [0x000000062b400000, 0x0000000755600000, 0x0000000763c00000)
  object space 4884480K, 88% used [0x000000062b400000,0x0000000732f35658,0x0000000755600000)
 PSPermGen       total 21504K, used 5552K [0x0000000620e00000, 0x0000000622300000, 0x000000062b400000)
  object space 21504K, 25% used [0x0000000620e00000,0x000000062136c2a8,0x0000000622300000)
}
Event: 922.006 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=300 (full 26):
 PSYoungGen      total 1647104K, used 1032655K [0x0000000763c00000, 0x0000000800000000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 794112K, 100% used [0x0000000763c00000,0x0000000794380000,0x0000000794380000)
  from space 852992K, 27% used [0x0000000794380000,0x00000007a2c73d88,0x00000007c8480000)
  to   space 852992K, 0% used [0x00000007cbf00000,0x00000007cbf00000,0x0000000800000000)
 ParOldGen       total 4884480K, used 4320469K [0x000000062b400000, 0x0000000755600000, 0x0000000763c00000)
  object space 4884480K, 88% used [0x000000062b400000,0x0000000732f35658,0x0000000755600000)
 PSPermGen       total 21504K, used 5552K [0x0000000620e00000, 0x0000000622300000, 0x000000062b400000)
  object space 21504K, 25% used [0x0000000620e00000,0x000000062136c2a8,0x0000000622300000)
Event: 922.276 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=300 (full 26):
 PSYoungGen      total 1707008K, used 777281K [0x0000000763c00000, 0x0000000800000000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 854016K, 0% used [0x0000000763c00000,0x0000000763c00000,0x0000000797e00000)
  from space 852992K, 91% used [0x00000007cbf00000,0x00000007fb610478,0x0000000800000000)
  to   space 852992K, 0% used [0x0000000797e00000,0x0000000797e00000,0x00000007cbf00000)
 ParOldGen       total 4884480K, used 4557979K [0x000000062b400000, 0x0000000755600000, 0x0000000763c00000)
  object space 4884480K, 93% used [0x000000062b400000,0x0000000741726ce0,0x0000000755600000)
 PSPermGen       total 21504K, used 5552K [0x0000000620e00000, 0x0000000622300000, 0x000000062b400000)
  object space 21504K, 25% used [0x0000000620e00000,0x000000062136c2a8,0x0000000622300000)
}
Event: 922.277 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=301 (full 27):
 PSYoungGen      total 1707008K, used 777281K [0x0000000763c00000, 0x0000000800000000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 854016K, 0% used [0x0000000763c00000,0x0000000763c00000,0x0000000797e00000)
  from space 852992K, 91% used [0x00000007cbf00000,0x00000007fb610478,0x0000000800000000)
  to   space 852992K, 0% used [0x0000000797e00000,0x0000000797e00000,0x00000007cbf00000)
 ParOldGen       total 4884480K, used 4557979K [0x000000062b400000, 0x0000000755600000, 0x0000000763c00000)
  object space 4884480K, 93% used [0x000000062b400000,0x0000000741726ce0,0x0000000755600000)
 PSPermGen       total 21504K, used 5552K [0x0000000620e00000, 0x0000000622300000, 0x000000062b400000)
  object space 21504K, 25% used [0x0000000620e00000,0x000000062136c2a8,0x0000000622300000)

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 407.398 Thread 0x00007f913c00a000 Uncommon trap: reason=array_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007f913922585c method=java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeLo(IIII)V @ 461
Event: 407.399 Thread 0x00007f913c00a000 Uncommon trap: reason=array_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007f9139227f38 method=java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeHi(IIII)V @ 234
Event: 418.240 Thread 0x00007f913c00a000 Uncommon trap: reason=array_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007f9139223518 method=java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeHi(IIII)V @ 642
Event: 418.240 Thread 0x00007f913c00a000 Uncommon trap: reason=array_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007f9139223160 method=java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeHi(IIII)V @ 404
Event: 418.240 Thread 0x00007f913c00a000 Uncommon trap: reason=array_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007f9139223160 method=java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeHi(IIII)V @ 404
Event: 451.264 Thread 0x00007f913c00a000 Uncommon trap: reason=array_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007f913924bf94 method=java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeLo(IIII)V @ 129
Event: 451.264 Thread 0x00007f913c00a000 Uncommon trap: reason=array_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007f913922ad98 method=java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeHi(IIII)V @ 509
Event: 451.264 Thread 0x00007f913c00a000 Uncommon trap: reason=array_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007f913922ad98 method=java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeHi(IIII)V @ 509
Event: 610.071 Thread 0x00007f913c00a000 Uncommon trap: reason=array_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007f913924bf94 method=java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeLo(IIII)V @ 129
Event: 823.140 Thread 0x00007f913c00a000 Uncommon trap: reason=array_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00007f91392518f8 method=java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeHi(IIII)V @ 160

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 85.592 Thread 0x00007f913c00a000 Threw 0x0000000765556120 at /build/buildd/openjdk-7-7u55-2.4.7/build/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 85.602 Thread 0x00007f913c00a000 Threw 0x000000076555a348 at /build/buildd/openjdk-7-7u55-2.4.7/build/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 85.603 Thread 0x00007f913c00a000 Threw 0x000000076555ef18 at /build/buildd/openjdk-7-7u55-2.4.7/build/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 85.604 Thread 0x00007f913c00a000 Threw 0x0000000765562328 at /build/buildd/openjdk-7-7u55-2.4.7/build/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 85.660 Thread 0x00007f913c00a000 Threw 0x000000076570ac68 at /build/buildd/openjdk-7-7u55-2.4.7/build/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 88.562 Thread 0x00007f913c00a000 Threw 0x000000076637c7e8 at /build/buildd/openjdk-7-7u55-2.4.7/build/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 88.563 Thread 0x00007f913c00a000 Threw 0x00000007663905b0 at /build/buildd/openjdk-7-7u55-2.4.7/build/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 88.692 Thread 0x00007f913c00a000 Threw 0x000000076662db70 at /build/buildd/openjdk-7-7u55-2.4.7/build/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 88.694 Thread 0x00007f913c00a000 Threw 0x00000007666351d8 at /build/buildd/openjdk-7-7u55-2.4.7/build/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 88.697 Thread 0x00007f913c00a000 Threw 0x000000076664a640 at /build/buildd/openjdk-7-7u55-2.4.7/build/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1244

Events (10 events):
Event: 834.875 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation done
Event: 870.630 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation
Event: 870.681 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation done
Event: 887.064 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation
Event: 887.089 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation done
Event: 887.429 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation
Event: 887.800 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation done
Event: 921.224 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation
Event: 921.312 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation done
Event: 922.006 Executing VM operation: ParallelGCFailedAllocation


Dynamic libraries: [section omitted]

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xmx7500m 
java_command: playingAgent.tartanian7.HUNLHEServer 10.136.57.208 18374
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:Tartanian7Files/gurobi/gurobi563/linux64/bin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:Tartanian7Files/gurobi/gurobi563/linux64/lib
SHELL=/bin/bash

Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0x918620], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0x918620], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0x795e30], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGPIPE: [libjvm.so+0x795e30], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0x795e30], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0x795e30], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGUSR2: [libjvm.so+0x795cd0], sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGHUP: [libjvm.so+0x795eb0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGINT: [libjvm.so+0x795eb0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGTERM: [libjvm.so+0x795eb0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGQUIT: [libjvm.so+0x795eb0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty)
uname:Linux 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64
libc:glibc 2.19 NPTL 2.19 
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k, NPROC 59937, NOFILE 4096, AS infinity
load average:1.69 1.63 1.14

/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:        7693824 kB
MemFree:          122376 kB
Buffers:            1260 kB
Cached:            24844 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          7465916 kB
Inactive:          16052 kB
Active(anon):    7455880 kB
Inactive(anon):      200 kB
Active(file):      10036 kB
Inactive(file):    15852 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                40 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       7455848 kB
Mapped:             6080 kB
Shmem:               236 kB
Slab:              19748 kB
SReclaimable:      10880 kB
SUnreclaim:         8868 kB
KernelStack:         856 kB
PageTables:        18700 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     3846912 kB
Committed_AS:    7890140 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:       14888 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359719127 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:     7872512 kB
DirectMap2M:           0 kB


CPU:total 2 (16 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 62 stepping 4, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, aes, erms, ht, tsc

/proc/cpuinfo:
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 62
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 v2 @ 2.50GHz
stepping    : 4
microcode   : 0x415
cpu MHz     : 2500.058
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 32
initial apicid  : 32
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu de tsc msr pae cx8 apic sep cmov pat clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm ida arat epb pln pts dtherm fsgsbase erms
bogomips    : 5000.11
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 62
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 v2 @ 2.50GHz
stepping    : 4
microcode   : 0x415
cpu MHz     : 2500.058
cache size  : 25600 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 32
initial apicid  : 32
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu de tsc msr pae cx8 apic sep cmov pat clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm ida arat epb pln pts dtherm fsgsbase erms
bogomips    : 5000.11
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:



Memory: 4k page, physical 7693824k(122376k free), swap 0k(0k free)

vm_info: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.51-b03) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.7.0_55-b14), built on Apr 17 2014 20:08:07 by "buildd" with gcc 4.8.2

time: Sat May 31 19:05:34 2014
elapsed time: 927 seconds
```

Comment: Looks like you didn't understood the most voted post in your question.

Comment: I'm now declaring each row of the array separately, so it shouldn't have the fragmentation issue described before, as commenter JimN suggested. It shouldn't be requesting a huge block of contiguous memory anymore.

Comment: But now you have lot of smaller contiguous memory blocks. And there's this point when there's no such contiguous memory block available. Which means that you're experiencing the same problem. And you will if you keep using this bad design.

Comment: this isn't a *follow up to a thread*, this isn't a forum, and it is not allowed to be used as one!

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate question, since I thought requesting smaller contiguous blocks would be different from a large one. But regardless, can you please suggest a better design? Or a link I could look at?

Comment: This question is a duplicate because it is a follow up. The answers provided there didn't helped you to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at nio byte buffers and allocateDirect. Memory is allocated outside JVM heap space. You will have some code refactoring work to do but since you need such large chunks of memory ByteBuffers might give you some relief.

From the JavaDoc

A direct byte buffer may be created by invoking the allocateDirect factory method of this class. The buffers returned by this method typically have somewhat higher allocation and deallocation costs than non-direct buffers. The contents of direct buffers may reside outside of the normal garbage-collected heap, and so their impact upon the memory footprint of an application might not be obvious. It is therefore ***recommended that direct buffers be allocated primarily for large, long-lived buffers*** that are subject to the underlying system's native I/O operations. In general it is best to allocate direct buffers only when they yield a measureable gain in program performance.

Comment: This answer should be posted in the first question from OP.

Comment: Thanks! I am working on an implementation with ByteBuffers now. Stupid question; if I am trying to represent the two-dimensional array of floats from the OP in a ByteBuffer, it looks like I would need something like ByteBuffer A_BB = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(NUM_SEQ_TOTAL_P1 * NUM_SEQ_TOTAL_P2 * 4), and use appropriate indexing to access elements?